# How to find smallest sub-list in a list of list that also includes integers

Tags: python, list, loops

Basically, i have a board of size N (lets say 4) with the biggest elements inside also of size N. I need to find the length of the smallest list in each row like in the following example:
 `row = [[1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4], 3, [1, 2]]`
should return the length of [1,2] and the index of that sublist but it returns an error because 3 is before it

I've written this

```
def full(puzzle):
    min = 0
    for i in range(len(puzzle)):
           for j in range(1 ,len(puzzle)):
               if isinstance(puzzle[i][j] , list):
                   if len(puzzle[i][j-1]) < len(puzzle[i][j]):
                       min = len(puzzle[i][j-1])
                       pos = (i , j-1)
    return pos
```

But the code doesnt work when j-1 is not a list.
How would i make it so the function would compare the length of puzzle[i][j] to j-2, (or 3 if j-1 and j-2 are also not lists etc..)

edit: and since row is in board, id love for the code to return the index of both the row and column.

Comment: Whats the expected output for your example?

Comment: If you're just trying to find the smallest sublist, while ignoring non-list items: `min(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, list), rows), key=len)`

Comment: @SerialLazer , expected output is the length of [1,2] so 2.

Comment: @PaulM. Thank you!, but is there a way to make that return the index ?

Comment: It would probably be better to change your data representation so that it's homogenous - having a list containing either lists of integers or single integers makes it more complicated to manage. Couldn't you have a list of one item (`[3]`) instead of just `3`?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Its just that the sublists mean the different possibilities while when it isnt a list its that the program is certain of the right value, so in my functions i just skip over ints

Comment: You could as easily check if you have a list of length one, and the right value would always be at `your_list[0]` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the key attribute of `min` somehow like this

```
row = [[1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4], 3, [1, 2]]
def func(item):
    return len(item) if type(item)==list else 999
sublist=min(row,key=func)
print('index of smallest list=',row.index(sublist))
print('length of smallest list=',len(sublist))
```

Comment: This works great, just wondering, if i were to change my input from row to board, how would i make it so that it would ouput the index of the smallest list in the entire board as a tuple for both the row index and column index ie: return(i , j)

Comment: the code i have right now basically loops through the rows of the board, appending the minimum length list and its corresponding position to an additional list, and then finding the minimum length list from that list , i was wondering if there was a faster solution

Comment: I don't have a faster solution then the one you are stating.